# What does Oracle DB do for the first query of a clustered table?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a question about oracle clusters and clustered tables.

Essentially we created a cluster, a clustered table and a cluster index:

```
create cluster testcluster1(id number(5)) size 1000 storage(initial 1024m);

create table test_tab1(id number(5), num number(5), str2 varchar2(20),str3 varchar2(20)) cluster testcluster1(id);

create index test1clusterindex on cluster testcluster1;
```

Then we inserted data into the table:

```
declare

  lower NUMBER := 1;

  upper NUMBER := 10000000;

begin

  FOR i In lower .. upper LOOP

    INSERT INTO test_tab1 VALUES(floor(i / 800000),

                           floor(i / 800000),

                           'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

                           'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  END LOOP;

end;
```

The time required for an ordinary full table scan is ~ 6s:

```
select sum(t.num) from TEST_TAB1 t;
```

The time required for the first query of a cluster scan is ~61s:

```
select sum(t.num) from TEST_TAB1 t where t.id <= 4
```

The later queries of the same cluster scan is super fast though (~ 0.4s) because the cluster, the clustered table and the cluster index were loaded into the default buffer cache (we know this because flushing the buffer cache restores the long time ~61s  for the cluster scan). But other than loading the cluster and the clustered table (which takes ~ 6s even for a full table scan) in the first query of the cluster scan, Oracle DB should have done something else (which takes ~ 55s).

So our question here is what does oracle DB do in the first query of the cluster scan during this ~55s time? Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: You should start with looking at the explain plan, and if that does not demonstrate a difference that can explain this effect then use wait event tracing -- the latter will be the authoritative information on where that time has gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! We did the test using wait event tracing today and found out that the buffer caching for the full table scan and for the ranged cluster scan were different. The full table scan uses db_file_scatter read (which has multiblock read into many discontinuous SGA buffers) while the cluster scan uses db_file_sequential read (which has single block read sequentially into continuous SGA buffers). This may well explain the time difference for the full table scan and the first query of the cluster scan.

Answer (score 0):

The first query performs a full scan and reads the blocks in sequence. The second query performs a range scan on the cluster index and accesses the table for each id. That results in many more logical reads as well as random reads. The result is a slower query. Start with explain plan and you will see the access paths; then you can run with statistics or autotrace on and see what happens!